# how localethereum works with its browser wallet

Tags: wallets

I am currently using https://localethereum.com service, it has a browser based wallet, its [faq](https://localethereum.com/faq) mentions that

> The localethereum.com wallet is completely embedded inside of your
>   browser. Similar to how messages are secured, the localethereum wallet
>   is designed so that your Ethereum address private keys are generated
>   offline in your browser.

all I know from the faq is online server stores identity key, and the identity key is used to sign signed key pairs and Ethereum addresses

> Identity verification - Each pre‐key is signed by the identity key of
>   its owner so that you know you are always talking to the right person.
>
> MakerKeypublic and MakerKeysignature are submitted to localethereum's
>   server for safe-keeping. The private key is encrypted safely using
>   AES-256 with a random IV and stored online too (at least for now).
>   Alice goes ahead and generates and signs (using her identity key)
>   hundreds of Ethereum addresses.

First question, is this identity key a (public key/ private key pair), and it mentions that 'Once Bob verifies both signatures to Alice's public key', is this Alice's public key a identity key or public makerkey ?

Second question, as shown in the wallet

[image]

the web app shows the wallet address and it also allows me to export the private keys, as it generates the private keys offline, it seems not to store the private keys online as well, but if i change the browser or computer, why could i still get access to the wallet and private keys? it there a way to do it by not storing the wallet address and private key on the server ?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use it again. I've tried to buy twice, both times got cancelled by seller. First one said price went up slightly and wanted new order. Second one cancelled after 2 hours stating he ran out, which was clearly a lie because I rechecked the seller list and he was there, listing at a higher price now. I'm convinced most of the sellers don't have the ethereum they advertise, they just let orders come in, wait a couple of hours to see if prices drop so they can buy on exchanges to sell to u. If no price drop they can simply cancel your order, no financial or reputation risks to them at all. Please don't get scammed / scalped, if prices go down after u order I'm sure they would be more than happy to fulfill order

Answer (score 0):

How individual sellers work is their business. But to say that sellers don't have the ethereum they advertise is pure FUD. Localethereum uses escrow smart contracts to facilitate the transaction between buyers and sellers and ensure that you don't get scammed. More info here https://blog.localethereum.com/how-our-escrow-smart-contract-works/